# How to catch an error into forall plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I put this exception to avoid any error inserting some row but I don't know why I can run.

```
DECLARE
TYPE dataDate IS TABLE OF DATE;
l_dataDate dataDate;
BEGIN
select data1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_dataDate from USER.TABLE_DATA;
FORALL i IN l_dataDate.FIRST..l_dataDate.LAST
    BEGIN         
        INSERT INTO USER.DIMDATE SELECT
        to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')),
        to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYYMMDD')),
        l_dataDate(i),
        to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'DD')),
        to_char (l_dataDate(i), 'Day'),
        to_number(to_char (l_dataDate(i), 'MM')),
        to_char (l_dataDate(i), 'Month'),
        to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYY')) FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USER.DIMDATE WHERE COD_FECHA=to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))); 
        COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
    END;
END;
/
```

Is it posible to do something like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume that you want to do a `bulk collect ... save exceptions`.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1422998100346727312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you want to put a `save exceptions` in your `bulk collect`.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE dataDate IS TABLE OF DATE;
  l_dataDate dataDate;

  dml_errors EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA exception_init(dml_errors, -24381);
BEGIN
  select data1 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_dataDate 
    from USER.TABLE_DATA;

BEGIN
  FORALL i IN l_dataDate.FIRST..l_dataDate.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    INSERT INTO USER.DIMDATE 
      SELECT
          to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')),
          to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYYMMDD')),
          l_dataDate(i),
          to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'DD')),
          to_char (l_dataDate(i), 'Day'),
          to_number(to_char (l_dataDate(i), 'MM')),
          to_char (l_dataDate(i), 'Month'),
          to_number(to_char(l_dataDate(i), 'YYYY'))  
     FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM USER.DIMDATE 
                       WHERE COD_FECHA=to_number(
                                         to_char(l_dataDate(i), 
                                                 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))); 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN dml_errors
  THEN
    FOR i IN 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count
    LOOP
      <<do something with the exceptions>>
    END LOOP;
END;
```

For something like this, though, there appears to be no reason to use PL/SQL at all.  Just write a single `INSERT` statement possibly with DML error logging if `table_data` has invalid data that needs to be logged.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but What happen if for example in the second insert appears an error, the others rows won't insert because the exception is not into the foral statement.

Comment: @Igerras84 - Have you actually tested it?  `save exceptions` saves the exceptions.  If the second element of the collection generates an error, the `forall` will continue on.  It will then be reported in the outer exception handler and you can iterate through the `sql%bulk_exceptions` collection to get information about the errors.  This is different than what would happen if you had a `for` loop where you would have to handle the exceptions within the loop iteration.