# Postgres Insert as select from table ignore any errors

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, bulk-load

I am trying to bulk load records from a temp table to table using insert as select stmt and on conflict strategy do update.

I want load as many records as possible, currently if there any any foreign key violations no records get inserted, everything gets rolled back. Is there a way to insert valid records and skip the faulty records.

In https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477 I saw a strategy of going with the foreign table in the query to ignore the faulty rows. I don't want to do that too as I may have many foreign keys on that table and it will make my query more complex and table specific. I would like it to be generic.

Sample use case, if have 100 rows in the temp table and suppose row number 5 and 7 are causing insertion failure, I want to insert the rest 98 records and identify which two rows failed. 
I want to avoid inserting record by record and catch the error, as it is not efficient. I am doing this whole exercise to avoid loading a table row by row.

Oracle provides support to catch bulk errors at a shot.
Sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430893/8575780
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1422998100346727312

I have already explored options loading using copy, it catches not null constraints and other data type errors, but when foreign key violation happens nothing gets committed.

I am looking something closer to what pgloader is doing when it faces error.
https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgloader.html#batches-and-retry-behaviour

Comment: if i'm not mistaken 2 db statements will have to be used, one to identify faulty rows (and delete them) and one to insert the remaing rows. Else you can try the join table strategy